# Symfony Embed a Collection of Forms multiple tables

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have 3 tables/entities. I am trying to create form to persist data to all 3 table in one form. Entitities are to long that is why I haven't added here.

Entity Client I made an array collection in Client entity for other 2 entities.

```
    protected $Clientservice;
    protected $Hostingaccount;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->Clientservice = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->Hostingaccount= new ArrayCollection();
    }
    public function getClientservice()
    {
        return $this->Clientservice;
    }
    public function getHostingaccount()
{
    return $this->Hostingaccount;
}

    public function setClientservice($Clientservice)
    {
        $this->Clientservice = $Clientservice;

        return $this;
    }
    public function setHostingaccount($Hostingaccount)
    {
        $this->Hostingaccount = $Hostingaccount;

        return $this;
    }
```

And I Have 3 forms:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('CustomerID',IntegerType::class)
        ->add('Sex',TextType::class)
        ->add('Name',TextType::class)
        ->add('FirstName',TextType::class)
        ->add('LastName',TextType::class)
        ->add('Email', EmailType::class)
        ->add('Invoiceemail', EmailType::class)
        ->add('Iban', TextType::class)
        ->add('Bic', TextType::class)
        ->add('SEPAMandateID', TextType::class)
        ->add('LogoUrl', TextType::class)
        ->add('CreationDate', DateType::class)
        ->add('Clientservice', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => WhmAdminClientserviceType::class
        ))
        ->add('Hostingaccount', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => WhmAdminHostingAccountType::class
        ))
        ->getForm();

}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => Client::class
    ));
}
```

Clientservice form

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('Description',TextType::class);

}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => Clientservice::class
    ));
}
```

Hostingaccount form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('Domain',TextType::class)
        ->add('Domainip',IntegerType::class)
        ->add('UserName',TextType::class)
        ->add('Owner',TextType::class);

}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => Hostingaccount::class
    ));
}
```

In my controller I have the code like this:

```
 public function AddWhmAdminAction(Request $request)
{

    $Client = new Client();

    $form = $this->createForm(WhmAdminType::class, $Client);
    $form->add('submit', SubmitType::class, array(
        'label' => 'Create',
        'attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-default pull-left')
    ));
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $em->persist($Client);
        $em->flush();

        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('green', 'Product created!');
        return $this->redirectToRoute('whmAdmin');
        // flash msg
    }
    //return $form->createView();
    $build['form'] = $form->createView();
    return $this->render('whm/WhmAdminForm.html.twig', $build);

}
```

and in my view

```
{{ form_start(form) }}

{% for flashMessage in app.session.flashbag.get('green') %}

    {{ flashMessage }}

{% endfor %}


{{ form_end(form) }}
```

I followed  http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html and this is how far I got.
My form only shows the fields from Client. It does not shows field from Clientservice and hostingaccount. How can I show the fields from clientservice and hostingaccount in the same form as Client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `Clientservice` and `Hostingaccount` are in OneToOne or ManyToOne relationship then change:

```
->add('Clientservice', CollectionType::class, array(
    'entry_type' => WhmAdminClientserviceType::class
))
->add('Hostingaccount', CollectionType::class, array(
    'entry_type' => WhmAdminHostingAccountType::class
))
```

to:

```
->add('Clientservice', WhmAdminClientserviceType::class)
->add('Hostingaccount', WhmAdminHostingAccountType::class)
```

Otherwise leave your form builders and read about [adding and removing items](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#adding-and-removing-items)  in collection type.

Comment: It gives me this error The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class AppBundle\Entity\Clientservice, but is an instance of class Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view transformer that transforms an instance of class Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection to an instance of AppBundle\Entity\Clientservice. but when I changed  "data_class" to null it does show other field. when I persist data it only persist data to client not to clientservice en hostingaccount

Comment: Is the `Clientservice` and `Hostingaccount` ManyToOne relationship to `Client`?

Comment: I have like this /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Clientservice", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $Clientservice;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Hostingaccount", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $Hostingaccount;  inside client entity

Comment: So you need to add script to build form set collection from prototype. See the documentation attached to my post.